# How to convert a char to a libc::c_char?

Tags: char, rust, ffi

I have a C function:

```
Node * first_element_by_path(const Node * node, const char * path, char delimiter);
```

And a Rust glue function:

```
pub fn first_element_by_path(node: *mut CNode, path: *const c_char, delimiter: c_char) -> *mut CNode;
```

It expects a `c_char` as delimiter. I want to send a `char` to it, but `c_char` is a `i8` and not a `char`. How can I convert a Rust `char` to `i8` or `c_char` in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are asking the question:

> How do I fit a 32-bit number into an 8-bit value?

Which has the immediate answer: "throw away most of the bits":

```
let c = rust_character as libc::c_char;
```

However, that should cause you to stop and ask the questions:

- Are the remaining bits in the right encoding?
- What about all those bits I threw away?

Rust `char`s allow encoding all Unicode scalar values. What is *your* desired behavior for this code:

```
let c = '' as libc::c_char;
```

It's probably not to create the value `-87`, a non-ASCII value! Or this less-silly and perhaps more realistic variant, which is `-17`:

```
let c = 'ï' as libc::c_char;
```

You then have to ask: what does the C code mean by a character? What encoding does the C code think strings are? How does the C code handle non-ASCII text?

The safest thing may be to assert that the value is within the ASCII range:

```
let c = 'ï';
let v = c as u32;
assert!(v <= 127, "Invalid C character value");
let v = v as libc::c_char;
```

Instead of asserting, you could also return a `Result` type that indicates that the value was out of range.

> should I change my function (the one that will call the glue function) to receive a `c_char` instead of a `char`?

That depends. That may just be pushing the problem further up the stack; now *every* caller has to decide how to create the `c_char` and worry about the values between 128 and 255. If the semantics of your code are such that the value has to be an ASCII character, then *encode that in your types*. Specifically, you can use something like the [ascii crate](https://crates.io/crates/ascii).

In either case, you push the possibility for failure into someone else's code, which makes your life easier at the potential expense of making the caller more frustrated.

Comment: Making the assert would be the correct way to handle it or should I change my function (the one that will call the glue function) to receive a `c_char` instead of a `char`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed and very insightful answer!